# Android browser doesn't update the url on address bar on jQuery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, android-browser

I am using jQuery mobile 1.3.1 to create a mobile web site. I have some basic content in the page

```
<a href="login" data-role="button">Login</a>
<a href="signup" data-role="button">Signup</a>
```

when user clicks to one of the buttons he should go to mydomain/login or mydomain/signup . In chrome on android or in safari on iOS it works like this way but on android browser url is still mydomain after the click. It doesn't add signup or login to the end of the link. It still works jQuery mobile makes an ajax request and shows the login or signup page but when I refresh the page of course it goes back to mydomain rather than my domain/login .

In some web sites I heard android 4 is not supporting html5 history. Is that happening because of that? And is there any solution to solve this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.